# zsh Prompt expansion: Why does %b cancel background colour?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, prompt

I'm running Zsh 5.2 on MacOS, running in Terminal.app with TERM set to `xterm-256color`.

When styling the PROMPT, I found that in this Zsh version, a `%b` cancels the effect of a previous `%K`. Consider this example:

```
print -P '12%K{green}34%B56%b78%k90'
```

This prints only 3456 with green background, not 345678, as I would have expected.

If I replace the %B...%b by %U...%u or %S...%s, 345678 receives the green background. It seems that only %b is implicitly cancelling the effect of %K.

Can somebody explain, why this is so?

Comment: Maybe this is a bug in _zsh 5.2_ or `xterm-256color`. Using _zsh 5.7.1-dev_ on Linux with `rxvt-unicode` or `xterm` I get the expected result. Can you narrow this down by trying another terminal emulator or a newer _zsh_ version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in *zsh 5.2*. It was fixed with this commit

```
commit e87aa8941fd7e13b039bf4d1664c6dc39a09313a
Author: Oliver Kiddle <opk@zsh.org>
Date:   Fri Jul 8 22:28:15 2016 +0200

    38809: fix tracking of colour attributes and restore them when turning bold off
```

which was incorporated into *zsh 5.3*.